# Update inserts different hash values than a select does

Tags: sql-server, hash, md5

I am trying to update a new column in my SQL Server `user` table with the hash of another column.

when I test the conversion with a select statement it will return the correct MD5 hash that I get from online hash generators.

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', 'valuetohash'), 2)
```

when I use this same conversion in an update statement as shown below I get a different value, inserted then the select statement with the same value hashed.

```
UPDATE users SET [newcolumn1] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', column1), 2)
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what type is your column `column1`?

Comment: also your data may contain spaces or non printable characters which will change the hash value

Comment: Turns out this was the issue the column1 is nvarchar.  however I can't seem to use nvarchar is the hash.  The only way to make this work is to use it on a column that is not nvarchar which means I can't allow doublebyte characters.

Answer (score 1):

The value you have in `users.column1` does not exactly match the value you are manually passing through `HashBytes` as a test. To confirm that this works when the values are the same, try:

```
DECLARE @users TABLE (
    column1 VARCHAR(100),
    newcolumn1 VARCHAR(32)
)

INSERT INTO @users
SELECT 'some text', NULL

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', 'some text'), 2)
UPDATE @users SET newcolumn1 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', column1), 2)
SELECT newcolumn1 FROM @users
```

You'll see that the results you get from each `SELECT` are the same, because the values of `'some text'` and `@users.column1` are identical.

Try comparing your values first:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN column1 = 'expectedValue' 
            THEN 'MATCH' 
            ELSE 'DIFFERENCE' 
       END AS MatchCheck
FROM users
```

or

```
SELECT column1
FROM users
WHERE column1 = 'expectedValue'
```

If you get results from the first query where `MatchCheck` = `'MATCH'` or results from the second query at all, then you should also get results form your `UPDATE` which give the hash you expect, as the values are the same.

As mentioned by [ughai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4436237/ughai) in the comments, it's most likely you have some spaces or non-printable characters in the values in your database which you are not including when you dry-run the hashing, hence the different results.

Answer (score 0):

Check data type from source & target columns, hashkey generally has varbinary(8000) data types.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).